# how can I keep track of the selected div , and update overview component?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a component where the component can automatic adds a class to `overview-card` to remove 70% , and adds a margin to `job-explain`, but on the other hand I want if the first overview is active , and  `job-explain` is open then just update `job-explain`with the content from the div

```
const FeedView = () => {
    const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
    const onClick = (e) => setShowResults(!showResults);
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);

    return (
        <>
        {feed.map(post => 
            <div className={`${showResults ? "job-card overview-card job-overview-card-70-minus" : "job-card overview-card"}`} key={makeid()} onClick={onClick}>
            </div>
            <div className={`${showResults ? "job-explain job-explain-visibility" : "hidden"}`} >
                update content here if already open the first overview-card
            </div>
      )}
      </>
    )
```

Comment: If I’m understanding this right, you would pass some property of your post object into the onClick handler and call setSelected with it.

Comment: yeah, but at the same keep update it if the first overview is open